# GLUT in small part of window. (winapi)

Tags: winapi, glut, freeglut

Is there a simple way to see openGL images only in small part of window?
I need some controls like buttons or checkboxes on the rest part. How it is possible?
Is it possible with (free)GLUT?

===Edit1===

In other words, I need a children window, which will be the quarter of my existing window. Then I have to change the next code in order to pack the glut entity in this small window.

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowPosition(20, 20);
glutInitWindowSize(frame_width, frame_height);
glutCreateWindow("MyVideo2");
```

Comment: Create a child window and put your GLUT stuff there.

Comment: @andlabs , yes, you understand what I want, but I am asking about how to create such child window that has no borders, maximize/mininmize buttons, title, etc.

Comment: [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx), like you create any other window, too. If you need an introduction, make sure to read [windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595.aspx) as well.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the link. You don't know how to attach one window to another, do you? Is it possible? I think yes, because old versions of 3DMax and AutoCad had viewports with 3d graphics...

Comment: That's what a child window is. I suggest reading a tutorial on Windows programming (I imagine you are opening a window directly with GLUT right now?).

Comment: @andlabs, Yes, you are right! So I've edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains the way of creation such program minutely in detail, it works for me with few ommited moments like that I couldn't set calling OnTimer on the picture control in VS13 so I have to set it on the dialog.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm